# Computing the normalisation of posterior Normal Inverse Wishart

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods

My question revolves around numerical problems when computing the posterior Normal-Inverse-Wishart distribution for Gaussian parameters.

Let $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}_{i=1}^N$ be $N$ i.i.d. samples from a Gaussian $\mathcal{N}({\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma}})$. The Gaussian parameters themselves are Normal-Inverse-Wishart distributed

$$
\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma}\sim\text{NIW}(\mathbf{m}_0,\kappa_0,\mathbf{S}_0,\nu_0)
$$

The full density is defined [here](http://www.kamperh.com/notes/kamper_bayesgmm13.pdf). The full joint distribution $p(\{\mathbf{x_i}\}_i,\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma})$ has an analytic form since the Normal-Inverse-Wishart is conjugate to the Gaussian distribution.

Hence, we can analytically compute the "data marginal"

$$
p(\{\mathbf{x}_i\})=\int_{\mathbf{\mu}}\int_{\mathbf{\Sigma}}p(\{\mathbf{x_i}\}_i,\mathbf{\mu},\mathbf{\Sigma})d\mathbf{\mu}d\mathbf{\Sigma}=(2\pi)^{-ND/2}\frac{Z_{NIW}(D,\kappa_N,\nu_N,S_N)}{Z_{NIW}(D,\kappa_0,\nu_0,S_0)}\quad (1)
$$

where $\nu_N=\nu_0+N,\kappa_N=\kappa_0+N$, $D$ is data dimension and

$$
Z_{NIW}(D,\kappa,\nu,S):=2^{(\nu+1)D/2}\pi^{(D+1)D/4}\kappa^{-D/2}\text{det}(S)^{-\nu/2}\prod_{i=1}^D\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu+1-i}{2}\right)\quad(2)
$$

I work with $N=250$, so I get a numerical overflow error when computing the nominator in (1). This is because in the last terms of (2) the argument in $\Gamma((\nu_N+1-i)/2)$ is too large, i.e. $\Gamma(250)$ cannot be computed.

Does anyone have an idea how to work around this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Don't know what you are using but if you have access to a log gamma function, for example scipy does, then take the logarithm of $(1)$ and work with that instead

Comment: ah cool, thanks. I was already working with log but unknowingly that there is a log-gamma function. will post answer when i get to it